# Copy rows from one worksheet to another based on different columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a master sheet ("Perk") and want to copy all with a "y" in column A into the "Registration" sheet and all with a "y" in column B into the "Housing" sheet. With the current code, the correct information is copying into the registration sheet. The housing sheet is only pulling in the first record.

```
Sub extractdata()
    Dim x As Long, lastrow

    lastrow = Sheets("Perk").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("Housing").Range("A2:AW500").ClearContents
    Sheets("Registration").Range("A2:AW500").ClearContents
    For x = 2 To lastrow
    If Worksheets("Perk").Cells(x, 1) Like "y*" Or Worksheets("Perk").Cells(x, 1) Like "Y*" Then
    Worksheets("Perk").Cells(x, "A").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Registration").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If

    If Worksheets("Perk").Cells(x, 2) Like "y*" Or Worksheets("Perk").Cells(x, 2) Like "Y*" Then
    Worksheets("Perk").Cells(x, "B").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Housing").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1)
    End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: right now you have it that if Column A has the y it goes into Registration and only if Column A does not have y and Column B has y will it go to housing.  If you want it to go to housing regardless whether A has y you will ned to split it into two distinct ifs not one with ElseIF.

Comment: thanks! I made the update. now the rows are only copying to Housing if there's y in Column A & Column B. or if there's multiple rows with y in Column B then only the last row is getting copied into Housing. Registration copies correctly.

Comment: Is your question accurately reflecting what the code in the question is doing?  It seems to be saying one thing in the question ("With the current code, the correct information is copying into the registration sheet. The housing sheet is only pulling in the first record."), but your last comment ("now the rows are only copying to Housing if there's y in Column A & Column B. or if there's multiple rows with y in Column B then only the last row is getting copied into Housing.") seems to contradict that.

Comment: Is anything happening while your code is running which might be changing which sheet is "active" (e.g. are you stepping through the code and switching sheets to see whether the statement that was just executed worked)?  If so, the unqualified `Cells` (which will default to referring to the active sheet) could cause weird results.

Comment: The answer by Imran Malek almost certainly will solve your immediate issue, but you should still change the unqualified `Cells` references (such as `Cells(x, 1)` etc) to qualify them with the appropriate worksheet, probably `Worksheets("Perk").Cells(x, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this as your perk sheet ,

[image]

This as output of registration sheet

[image]

and this as output of housing sheet

[image]
What's happening here is a result of statement

```
Worksheets("Perk").Cells(x, "A").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Housing").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

You are trying to find the empty row for housing sheet by checking the empty cell in column A which is wrong.

Haven't tried but if you change that line with this it should work

```
 Worksheets("Perk").Cells(x, "A").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Housing").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1)
```

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for your comment.I have added the fix.

Comment: @YowE3K I changed it as per your suggestion.